# Post on Facebook page as admin iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, admin, facebook-page, facebook-sdk-3.1

I need to make a post on a my own fanpage as the admin.
I created this code hopping that passing the id of the page "fbPageID" would leave the post on that page, but it actually leaves the post on my profile.

```
NSArray *publishPerms = @[@"manage_pages",@"publish_actions", @"publish_stream"];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:publishPerms     defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if (session.isOpen) {
            [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:self.textBox.text place:fbPageID tags:nil completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if (error){
                    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"POSTED %@",result);
                }

            }];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"session not open");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

## This is helpfull for Post on user Facebook..

1. Step 1 - Import FBSDK in your project
2. Step 2 - Login Authentication

   ```
   NSDictionary *params = @{
   @"message": @"This is a test message",
                            };
   /* make the API call */
   FBSDKGraphRequest *request_ = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                 initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request_ startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection   *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error) {
       // Handle the result
   }];
   ```